# Displaying images depending on iPhone device type

Tags: iphone, macros, device

I am trying to make my app run on an iPad and an iPad retina, with images of higher res on Retina. As I define all the images and sizes in macros, I need to create an automated switching which would redefine the macros.

```
#define IMAGE1 @"Image1"
```

would become

```
#define IMAGE1 @"Image1_Retina"
```

for example. The code doesn't have to change. I just need an automated switching between images and resolution. Is there a way to just change the macros without touching the rest of the code?

Comment: Macros are evaluated at compile time. You should have a look at the UIDevice class instead.

Comment: I have checked, but it seems I would have to update the whole code, or at least cut and paste two versions of the code with the appropriate images. I am trying to avoid this. Is there a solution to just switch a batch of images instead of changing the code?

Comment: Incredible! I can't believe I actually spent hours trying to find an easy way to code this! All I need to do is append @2x to all my retina images, then build the app on a retina device and it just works!

Comment: Are you using UIImage/UIImageView? It will handle the choice for you so long as you have "Image1.png" and "Image1@2x.png" in your app bundle.